# MapBox - Search for markers from Javascript

Tags: javascript, search, csv, mapbox, markers

I am working on a (private) school project.
I am new to javascript and ran into a problem.

On this page, you will find the project: http://www.curlydutchman.nl/fishinglocations/
What I want is to make a search box in where I can search for the markers that are on the map.

I followed this with success (but removed them again): https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering/
but the problem is that these markers are loaded in from a CSV file. It seems that I cannot edit these pins, and add them to my 'search by filter' list... Also, if I would copy the coordinates of my pins in to the CSV file, they would show up on a different location of the map.

So I believe that my only solution is to link a search field to the markers that are located in my Javascript.

Has anyone got an idea on what the solution to my problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

You approach of searching for markers on the map using `setFilter` for the GeoJSON looks correct.

> if I would copy the coordinations of my pins in to the CSV file, they would show up on a different location of the map.

This may be a function of coordinates being reversed.

GeoJSON = longitude, latitude
CSV = latitude, longitude (depends on the field names)